Kernel disconnecting when running dask clusters
I have several large paquet files which i have loaded into a dask dataframe, however, when i perform operations such as .compute() to get the result of a small subset of the data, the Jupyter notebook kernel disconnects.
I am running dask distributed on an HPC cluster and the total memory of my dask scheduler is about 30.96TB. The dask cluster is configured to have 63 workers, each with 500gb memory and 1 thread. I'm not sure why i am experiencing kernel disconnect when I try to do certain operations such as persisting data in memory, .compute() or .set_index().
I would really appreciate any help with this.
Here is my code:
'''
df = dd.read_parquet(file_path)
df=df.drop(['facility','pid'], axis=1)
#Format the datetime without milliseconds
df['timestamp'] = dd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['timestamp'] = dd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')

df=df.set_index('timestamp')
df=df.persist()

'''

Hi, do you get an error or something? set_index ca be a costly operation, how big is your dataset? How are you creating the Dask cluster? How much memory do you have on Jupyter kernel side?
